# Href customizing from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an **<a>** tag:

```
<a id="down" data-Id="" type="button"  href="@Url.Action("InvestigatorDetailsDownload", "ClinicalRegistryManager")?investigatorId={data-Id}">download</a>
```

I am setting this attribute (data-id) from jQuery:

```
function showInvDetails(id) {

  $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("
      method ", "
      controller ")?investigatorId=" + id

  }).done(function(data) {
      if (data) {
          console.log(id);
          $('#down').data("Id", id);
      }
  });
}
```

I want to set that id in the href of the a tag, how do I do that?

Comment: you mean change the id of the anchor?

Comment: href need to pass an id, which is being set in jquery.

Comment: @Vispriya - I understand that you might be new to this but your question makes no sense. Please try and describe the problem in plain english. Also, please explain what id(data-id) means **to you**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `href` attribute as

```
$('#down').attr('href', "@Url.Action("InvestigatorDetailsDownload", "ClinicalRegistryManager")?investigatorId=" + id);
```

Also note, when using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) jQuery uses internal cache. The statement `data(key)` will read **default** value only from `data-key` attribute afterwards it will use internal cache. the statement `.data( key, value )` will store data in internal cache it will not update DOM.

Comment: Am I wrong about that not being a proper string value? To me that second string param screams please escape me, I understand I could be totally wrong. What syntax is that? Does @Url.Action("InvestigatorDetailsDownload", "ClinicalRegistryManager") get replaced by some sort of preprocessor?

Comment: @DaveThomas, Yes `Url.Action()` is  [tag:asp.net-mvc]  preprocessor.

Comment: this is complete speculation in such an unclear question. you should try and answer the actual question, or ask for clarification

Comment: @DaveThomas, why are you apologising? my comment was directed at the answer

Comment: @DaveThomas, No need to apologize, once your edit was rejected, You are not involved in this at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#down').data('Id', id);
```

> jQuery data() - Store arbitrary data associated with the specified
>   element and/or return the value that was set.

[data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) you can imagine it as a *hidden* attribute associated with the anchor that jQuery creates for you and lets you get the value back whenever you need it

to change the actual id you need to use `attr()` like this:

```
$('#down').attr('Id', id);
```

Comment: `data()` will create a _hidden_ attribute? No. jQuery uses internal cache to store arbitrary data associated with element.

Comment: you're right, it won't. but how do you explain **Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.** to someone who asks a question like that? `data-id` usualy denotes an attribute. in any case, whoever wants more details, the link is there

Comment: @Satpal - you're preaching to the choire. the link for data() is already in my answer. you just missed it, again

Comment: I have issue with the term _hidden attribute_, You can use more acceptable term _internal cache_